# Show certain characters when user selects a value from lightning-combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working with a lightning-combobox to show only certain characters when user selects a value from the drop down list. Can someone help how I can achieve this? Below is the code that I tried from my end.

HTML file:

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <lightning-combobox
        name="progress"
        label="New"
        style="width: 200px;"
        value={value}
        options={comboOptions}
        onchange={handleChange}>

    </lightning-combobox>

</lightning-card>
```

JS File:

```
    value = 'sayHello';

get comboOptions() {
    return [
        {label: 'Say Hello(ABCD)', value: 'sayHello'},
        {label: 'Say Hello(XYZ)', value: 'sayHelloxyz'}
    ]
}
```

Current Output:

[image]

Expected output:
[image]

NOTE: I have a separator as open bracket in the combobox values.

Comment: Can you rephrase your ques?

Comment: @snl, When user selects a value from drop down, it should show the value until ( symbol as selected value but the drop down selected value should show the complete name. I added screen shots to explain it correct way. I wasn't sure on how I can explain in other way. Please see the expected result screenshot.